# CosmosDB (MongoDB) does restore failure and misleading info

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to restore a MongoDB database backup (native mongodb dump) on Azure CosmosDB. It always completes (so it says) but I always end up wih a fraction of the documents in the backup.

Works fine if I restore the same database backup onto a standard MongoDB installation but fails consistently on Azure CosmoDB (MongoDB).

What am I missing here? Is this a bug in Azure's CosmosDB?

Please see attached screenshot.

https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dashlike.com/support/Screen+Shot+2019-06-11+at+7.13.12+pm.png

https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dashlike.com/support/Screen+Shot+2019-06-11+at+7.13.34+pm.png

Comment: If the restore works fine on a standard MongoDB deployment, I suspect you are encountering unsupported features or limits in CosmosDB's MongoDB emulation. For example, CosmosDB currently has a 2MB maximum document size (versus MongoDB's 16MB) and also imposes some API request limits. It seems unusual that you wouldn't get an error when restoring the data, but CosmosDB may not be returning the expected result. Comparing the `_id`s between your Cosmos & MongoDB deployments to find the missing documents might provide some hints on what is different.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's worth noting that the original backup was taken from an existing CosmosDB (MongoDB) database so the document size should not be an issue. I did, however, run into an issue with size limitation in a separate instance - with only a 6KB document (it was intermittent ).

Comment: From your description I thought you had taken a backup from MongoDB and restored into Cosmos. What version does `mongorestore --version` report? If a backup from Cosmos doesn't restore into Cosmos, that suggests data/index compatibility shouldn't be a problem unless the deployments have different options enabled. Perhaps the inserts are being rate limited by Request Units (RUs). Have you looked at the database metrics in the Azure portal to see if requests are being throttled? Your issue generally sounds like it might be best handled by Cosmos support.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a paid support plan with Microsoft. Someone did reach out to me recently but our conversations have not been very fruitful.  Anyways, I did find multiple issues with Microsoft's current implementation of MongoDb. As at this moment, it appears to be severely crippled in many ways. So, Í've decided to move my MongoDb workload out of CosmosDB and into a native MongoDb instance.